# Textbox binding does not work ,when changes are made

Tags: data-binding, binding, bind

Hoping
I have an object (skuform),whose property(SKUCode) is bound to a textbox. 
If I run this form , change the value in the textbox (say "test123"), and hit the button, I notice that the object's (skuForm) property does not reflect the new value ("test123"), could you please suggest what could be wrong.

```
<td>
    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtSKUCode"  
                   text='<%# skuForm.SKUCode %>' 
                   EnableViewState="true"
                   Wrap="false" 
                   ontextchanged="txtSKUCode_TextChanged">
    </telerik:RadTextBox>
</td></tr> 

<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   onclick="RadButton1_Click">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set RadTextBox DataContext property to class wich implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface. So when PropertyChanged event will occurs, you RadTextBox will change his value.

You can see sample of this on [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: The question is about ASP.NET and Web Forms.  The link points to Silverlight and does not apply (but would be correct if the question was about silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

When do you call `DataBind`?  If you're not calling it on the postback, then it won't get updated.